# Insert multiple numbers related to the same entity SQL Server

Tags: php, html

I want to add multiple inserts at once but with the same data into every cell excepting the Serial_Numbers(voucher_sn into SQL) field.

So I have this PHP code for inserting my data into the SQL server from a input form:

```
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$client         = $_POST['client'];
$voucher_from   = $_POST['voucher_from'];
$voucher_to     = $_POST['voucher_to'];
$create_date    = $_POST['create_date'];
$exp_date       = $_POST['exp_date'];
$voucher_type   = $_POST['voucher_type'];

$tsql= "INSERT INTO as_vouchers
                ( client, voucher, create_date, exp_date, voucher_type )
        VALUES  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$voucher = 0;   //create the voucher var

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $tsql, 
        $client, $voucher, $create_date, $exp_date, $voucher_type);

//loop, incrementing the value of voucher only
for ( $voucher=$voucher_from; $voucher <= $voucher_to; $voucher++ ){
    // execute the query multiple times with new value for $voucher    
    if( sqlsrv_execute( $stmt ) === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
}

echo "lots of records added";

?>
```

- Part of the code. Where is the SN how should I format that HTML to have multiple records (from one number to another - eg. 100-105)

Comment: Well show us the web page code as that is a major part of your question

Comment: <p>
    <label for="voucher_sn">VoucherSN</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="voucher_sn" id="voucher_sn">
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="client">Client</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="client" id="client">
    </p> - Part of the code. Where is the SN how should I format that HTML to have multiple records (from one number to another - eg. 100-105)

Comment: If you place that into your question using the `Edit` link under the question, we could read and understand it

Comment: In answer to your comment unbder my answer count these ` ( client, voucher, create_date, exp_date, voucher_type )` and then count the `?` in this line `VALUES  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Comment: You have missed the point, you have no Loop in this new code, see my answer again, regardless of the change to the code you have made, the principal stays the same! And you do not want the from and to numbers all in the same insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some form modification, I created the working code for inserting and creating a while statement.

```
 $voucher = $voucher_from;

    $tsql= "INSERT INTO dbo.new_vouchers_ro ( 
        client,
        create_date,
        exp_date,
        voucher_type,
        voucher)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    while ($voucher <= $voucher_to){
        $var = array($client, $create_date, $exp_date, $voucher_type, $voucher);
        if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var))
        {
            die('Errors: ' . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));
        }
                $voucher++;
    echo "1 record added";   
    };
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple addition of a from and to field. Then change the php code to use a prepared statement, and loop (voucher_to - voucher_from) times executing the prepared query.

```
<p> 
    <label for="voucher_sn_from">VoucherSN From</label><br> 
    <input type="number" name="voucher_sn_from" id="voucher_sn_from"> 
</p> 
<p> 
    <label for="voucher_sn_to">VoucherSN To</label><br> 
    <input type="number" name="voucher_sn_to" id="voucher_sn_to"> 
</p> 

<p> 
    <label for="client">Client</label><br> 
    <input type="text" name="client" id="client"> 
</p>
```

Then loop in the code

```
$voucher_from   = $_POST['voucher_sn_from'];
$voucher_to     = $_POST['voucher_sn_to'];

$generate_date  = $_POST['generate_date'];
$expiry_date    = $_POST['expiry_date'];
$client         = $_POST['client'];
$is_used        = $_POST['is_used'];
$location_used  = $_POST['location_used'];
$used_date      = $_POST['used_date'];
$payed          = $_POST['payed'];
$payed_date     = $_POST['payed_date'];

$tsql= "INSERT INTO dbo.vouchers 
                ( voucher_sn, generate_date, expiry_date, client,
                is_used, location_used, used_date, payed, payed_date)
        VALUES  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$voucher = 0;   //create the voucher var

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $tsql, 
                            $voucher, $generate_date, $expiry_date, 
                            $client, $is_used, $location_used, 
                            $used_date, $payed, $payed_date);

//loop, incrementing the value of voucher only
for ( $voucher=$voucher_from; $voucher <= $voucher_to; $voucher++ ){
    // execute the query multiple times with new value for $voucher    
    if( sqlsrv_execute( $stmt ) === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
}

echo "lots of records added";
```

Comment: Connection established.

Fatal error: Param count and argument count don't match. in C:\xampp\htdocs\post_form.php on line 27 - I also updated the  code above

Comment: Sorry If I upset you, didn't called your answer wrong, I have made some changes cause they were neccesary. I get the same error code. I will update my code here.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248093/discussion-between-stefan3d-and-riggsfolly).